# Encoding in R: How to convert this string to UTF-8?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I am using R to read data from an old fame database. This works fine in general but I get unexpected encoding back when reading descriptions. E.g.:

```
a <- "\U3e34653c"
# is supposed to be 
"ä"
```

I tried to `iconv` my self around this problem but despite trying numerous possibilities I was not able to get it displayed in a proper way. my locale: en_US.UTF-8. Is there a way around replacing (sub) such strings?

Comment: I had a similar issue and had success converting first to 'latin1'.  Might be worth giving it a shot

Comment: This seems to be caused by your database, not R. The character ä is 0x000000e4 in Unicode, not 0x3e34653c (which is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the files with a different encoding string? As Ricardo suggests, perhaps Latin1? If not maybe some other exotic flavours:

```
f <- file( "myfile.db" , encoding = "Latin-1" )
dat <- readLines( f )
```

Can you link to some data?

Comment: I know it ain't the right unicode character. The problem is that I just get the character (whatever it is?) I have posted when I read from the db. Currently I am trying to figure out what I could do instead of regexp replacing.

Answer (score -1):

I had an identical problem when extracting data from SQL Server (via ODBC and the RODBC package). I solved it by changing the settings on the ODBC driver to treat all strings as unicode.

More specifically, I'm using Actual Technologies ODBC driver for SQL Server and under 'Advanced Language Settings' can specify 'Treat text types as Unicode' with an option for 'Multi-byte text encoding' to be set to UTF-8.