# Forcefully set Encoding from unknown to UTF-8 or any encoding in R?

Tags: r, encoding, iconv

I am reading data from an old proprietary database. Unfortunately I end up (only for some strings) with `Encoding(mychar_vector)` returning `"unknown"`. Unfortunately I am using a wrapper around a closed source `c hli` (host language interface), so there's probably not much I can do about that – if so I am glad to be proven wrong here...

However, looking at the string vector except for a few replacements I had to make (see my [related question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482351/encoding-in-r-how-to-convert-this-string-to-utf-8) using `gsub` the strings look ok. I would love to re-gain control of the encoding. Is there a way to forcefully set the encoding to UTF-8? I tried to

```
Encoding(mychar_vector) <- "UTF-8"
# or
mychar_vector <- enc2utf8(mychar_vector)
```

But none of this worked out. Just got `"unknown"` in return immediately after checking. Also looked into `iconv` but there is obviously no way converting from "unknown" to UTF-8 as there is no mapping.

Is there a way to tell R, that only UTF-8 characters are involved and thus the encoding can be set to UTF-8. Note that some of the elements of the vector are already UTF-8.

Comment: What OS are you using?  (FWIW, I'm on Windows, and also find this enormously frustrating).

Comment: OS X (10.7.5) and rstudio server on RHEL 6.3

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. When converting to UTF-8 I get a list of "unknown" and "UTF-8". It seems to be ignoring those strings that don't contain Chinese characters. I mean, it only encodes to UTF-8 those strings that contain Chinese characters.

Comment: This may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r

Comment: I put together a blog outlining how to diagnose some encoding issues with R: https://medium.com/@peterjgensler/functions-with-r-and-rvest-a-laymens-guide-acda42325a77 hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

I, too, have been down the encoding rabbit hole, and one of the important things I learned is that `"unknown"` encoding doesn't have to mean it's not UTF-8. Or bad. Or something that needs to be fixed.

Here are some examples:

```r
# Some string that might be UTF-8 or just some ASCII (but created in UTF-8 editor/environment)
ambiguous <- "wat"
Encoding(ambiguous)
#> [1] "unknown"

# Forced coercion to UTF-8 via stringi
ambiguous <- stringi::stri_enc_toutf8("wat", is_unknown_8bit = TRUE)

# Still ambiguous
Encoding(ambiguous)
#> [1] "unknown"

# Some pretty-sure-not-ASCII string
totallygermanic <- "wät"

# It's UTF-8 because that's what my RStudio and every other part of my env is set to
Encoding(totallygermanic)
#> [1] "UTF-8"

# Let's force it to be unknowm
Encoding(totallygermanic) <- "unknown"

# Still prints ok
totallygermanic
#> [1] "wät"

# What's its encoding now?
Encoding(totallygermanic)
#> [1] "unknown"

# Converting it to UTF-8 still prints ok
stringi::stri_enc_toutf8(totallygermanic)
#> [1] "wät"

# So the converted string is UTF-8, right? No.
Encoding(stringi::stri_enc_toutf8(totallygermanic))
#> [1] "unknown"

# Maybe we should just guess?
stringi::stri_enc_detect("wat")
#> [[1]]
#>     Encoding Language Confidence
#> 1 ISO-8859-1       en       0.75
#> 2 ISO-8859-2       ro       0.75
#> 3      UTF-8                0.15

stringi::stri_enc_detect("wät")
#> [[1]]
#>   Encoding Language Confidence
#> 1    UTF-8                 0.8
#> 2 UTF-16BE                 0.1
#> 3 UTF-16LE                 0.1
#> 4  GB18030       zh        0.1
#> 5   EUC-JP       ja        0.1
#> 6   EUC-KR       ko        0.1
#> 7     Big5       zh        0.1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The takeaway is this: If your string is not *obviously* non-ASCII, e.g. it only contains letters a-z, it *could* be ASCII, or it *could* be UTF-8, so you get an `unknown`, but that doesn't have to mean your string is not actually UTF-8, apparently. You may try to forcibly coerce the string, but in the process you *might* break something that was not broken at all. In my experience, it may be perfectly adequate to use some conversion function like `stringi::stri_enc_toutf8` on a variable/vector, test if it prints/works as expected, maybe using a regular expression filter for possibly problematic characters (as a German native we tend to look for `äöüß`).

Anway, if you want to dive into the nitty gritty I can recommend looking into the [`stringi` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.2.4/topics/stri_encode) and it's encoding functions. This package is the power behind [`stringr`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0), which provides a more high-level interface.

Answer (score 1):

When I have dealt with files that are not UTF-8 encoded properly, I have used iconv with great success to forcefully convert the file by simply running a bash script in my rmarkdown notebook:

```
iconv -c -t UTF-8 myfile.txt > Ratebeer-myfile.txt
```

You could also try this where file is your original file, and file-iconv is the modified file:

```
#iconv −f iso−8859−1 −t UTF−8 file.txt > file-iconv.txt
```

Verify the encoding with:

```
file -I file-iconv.txt
```

Let me know if this helps or not.