# Force character vector encoding from "unknown" to "UTF-8" in R

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, data.table

I have a problem with **inconsistent encoding of character vector** in R.

The text file which I read a table from is encoded (via `Notepad++`) in `UTF-8` (I tried with `UTF-8 without BOM`, too.).

I want to read table from this text file, convert it do `data.table`, set a `key` and make use of binary search. When I tried to do so, the following appeared:

> Warning message:
>       In `[.data.table`(poli.dt, "żżonymi", mult = "first") :
>       A known encoding (latin1 or UTF-8) was detected in a join column. data.table compares         the bytes currently, so doesn't support
>   *mixed* encodings well; i.e., using both latin1 and UTF-8, or if any unknown encodings are non-ascii and some of those are marked known and
>   others not. But if either latin1 or UTF-8 is used exclusively, and all
>   unknown encodings are ascii, then the result should be ok. In future
>   we will check for you and avoid this warning if everything is ok. The
>   tricky part is doing this without impacting performance for ascii-only
>   cases.

and binary search **does not work**.

I realised that my `data.table`-`key` column consists of both: "unknown" and "UTF-8" Encoding types:

```
> table(Encoding(poli.dt$word))
unknown   UTF-8 
2061312 2739122
```

I tried to convert this column (before creating a `data.table` object) with the use of:

- `Encoding(word) <- "UTF-8"`
- `word<- enc2utf8(word)`

but with no effect.

I also tried a few different ways of reading a file into R (setting all helpful parameters, e.g. `encoding = "UTF-8"`):

- `data.table::fread`
- `utils::read.table`
- `base::scan`
- `colbycol::cbc.read.table`

but with no effect.

## ==================================================

My R.version:

```
> R.version
           _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2014                        
month          03                          
day            06                          
svn rev        65126                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
nickname       Warm Puppy
```

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250                LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2 colbycol_0.8     filehash_2.2-2   rJava_0.9-6     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.1    reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.3
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `Encoding` function returns `unknown` if a character string has a "native encoding" mark (CP-1250 in your case) or if it's in ASCII.
To discriminate between these two cases, call:

```
library(stringi)
stri_enc_mark(poli.dt$word)
```

To check whether each string is a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, call:

```
all(stri_enc_isutf8(poli.dt$word))
```

If it's not the case, your file is definitely not in UTF-8.

I suspect that you haven't forced the UTF-8 mode in the data read function (try inspecting the contents of `poli.dt$word` to verify this statement). If my guess is true, try:

```
read.csv2(file("filename", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

or

```
poli.dt$word <- stri_encode(poli.dt$word, "", "UTF-8") # re-mark encodings
```

If `data.table` still complains about the "mixed" encodings, you may want to transliterate the non-ASCII characters, e.g.:

```
stri_trans_general("Zażółć gęślą jaźń", "Latin-ASCII")
## [1] "Zazolc gesla jazn"
```

Comment: Thank you! =) According to the result of `all(stri_enc_isutf8(poli.dt$word))`, it seems my file "is not in UTF-8 at all". However, I managed with the problem by using `hash` table object instead of `data.table`, which turns out to be faster in my particular problem and does not have such problems with endcoding.

Comment: Something important to note is that R seems to consider all byte codes less than 127 as ASCII together everything in your locale as 'unknown'.

Comment: `stri_encode(str, from="", to = "UTF-8")` does not seems to work for me, the object returns "unknown" with `Encoding()` or "ASCII" using `stri_enc_mark()`, not "UTF-8"

Comment: This isn't working for me. I have a character vector x, such that `all(stri_enc_isutf8(x)` returns `TRUE`, and `Encoding(x)` returns "unknown", but
`x <- stri_encode(x, "", "UTF-8"); Encoding(x)`
returns "unknown". Similarly 
`Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"; Encoding(x)`
returns "unknown"

Comment: Using iconv conversion, it says that: "unsupported conversion from 'unknown' to 'UTF-8'"

Comment: For me `poli.dt$word <- stri_encode(poli.dt$word, "", "UTF-8")` didn't work, but `stri_enc_toutf8(poli.dt$word)` did. I know it's not a common case since it converting to UTF-8 only, but may be useful for someone.

Comment: None of these are working for me.

Answer (score 15):

I could not find a solution myself to a similar problem. 
I could not translate back unknown encoding characters from txt file into something more manageable in R.

Therefore, I was in a situation that the same character appeared more than once in the same dataset, because it was encoded differently ("X" in Latin setting and "X" in Greek setting). 
However, txt saving operation preserved that encoding difference --- of course well-done.

Trying some of the above methods, nothing worked. 
The problem is well described [“cannot distinguish ASCII from UTF-8 and the bit will not stick even if you set it”](https://github.com/ropensci/tif/issues/2).

A good workaround is [" export your data.frame to a CSV temporary file and reimport with data.table::fread() , specifying Latin-1  as source encoding."](https://ourednik.info/maps/2018/04/19/unknown-column-force-encoding-of-an-entire-table-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r-on-windows/).

Reproducing / copying the example given from the above source:

```
package(data.table)
df <- your_data_frame_with_mixed_utf8_or_latin1_and_unknown_str_fields
fwrite(df,"temp.csv")
your_clean_data_table <- fread("temp.csv",encoding = "Latin-1")
```

I hope, it will help someone that.

Comment: Even this didn't work for me