# r display grep patterns and results side by side

Tags: r

I'm cleaning up and normalising imported data. I need to grep for many patterns in many columns and then update a column with the "clean" grepped pattern alongside the initial columns.

Target text is df (this is just a subset of actual columns and rows):

```
             name                  street_1               street_2        city
217916  Australia         49 Carbine Street     Donvale, Melbourne
197423              C/Guatemala 3, Local 11        Balearic Island
205195                        In Haiti: #30      Carrefour Digicel  Port Salut
```

Grep patterns are 247 countries. Final result should look like (columns above omitted for the sake of presentation):

```
          country
217916  Australia
197423  Guatemala
205195      Haiti
```

If a row returns several hits, they should be listed for later processing, e.g. `"Haiti, Australia"` or should it be `c("Haiti", "Australia")`?

```
                        country
217916  c("Haiti", "Australia")
```

Also: country names are too long when concatenated together for grep (with pipe delimiter), so I've had to resort to processing by block of countries, but there must be a better way.

The code I've come up with for grepping multiple columns is:

```
hits <- sapply(
  colnames(df), 
  function(x) grep(
    paste0(
      "(?<![a-z])(?:", 
      paste(head(countries$name, 120), collapse = "|"), 
      ")(?![a-z])"), 
    df[, x], 
    ignore.case = T, 
    perl = T))

results <- df[unique(unlist(hits)), sapply(hits, function(x) any(length(unlist(x)) > 0))]
```

This subsets df into rows and columns where hits are found, but is still far off the mark. I don't use the word boundary pattern `\\b` because I want to include digits and underscore in the boundaries.

Country names:

```
structure(list(name = c("Afghanistan", "Aland Islands", "Albania", 
"Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", 
"Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", 
"Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", 
"Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", 
"Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", 
"Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "British Indian Ocean Territory", 
"Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", 
"Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", 
"Chad", "Chile", "China", "Hong Kong, Special Administrative Region of China", 
"Macao, Special Administrative Region of China", "Christmas Island", 
"Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo?(Brazzaville)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", 
"C?te d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", 
"Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", 
"Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", 
"Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", 
"Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", 
"Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", 
"Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", 
"Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands", 
"Holy See?(Vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
"India", "Indonesia", "Iran, Islamic Republic of", "Iraq", "Ireland", 
"Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", 
"Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", 
"Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao PDR", "Latvia", 
"Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", 
"Luxembourg", "Macedonia, Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", 
"Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", 
"Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", 
"Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", 
"Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", 
"New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", 
"Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Palestinian Territory, Occupied", 
"Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "R?union", 
"Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint-Barth?lemy", 
"Saint Helena", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint-Martin (French part)", 
"Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Saint Vincent and Grenadines", 
"Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", 
"Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", 
"Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Sudan", 
"Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname?*", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", 
"Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic?(Syria)", 
"Taiwan, Republic of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania?*, United Republic of", 
"Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", 
"Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", 
"United States of America", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", 
"Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela?(Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Virgin Islands, US", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", 
"Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe")), .Names = "name", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-247L))
```

Target text sample data (50 rows/358626):

```
structure(list(org_order = c(12444L, 33914L, 44556L, 44592L, 
101963L, 109988L, 116027L, 116369L, 119774L, 129643L, 138317L, 
144409L, 144409L, 145106L, 162134L, 163578L, 163782L, 165580L, 
168297L, 169073L, 174144L, 182441L, 186903L, 187474L, 200151L, 
202672L, 203554L, 203696L, 204983L, 205534L, 205669L, 206412L, 
206998L, 209374L, 212087L, 214424L, 214549L, 214784L, 215966L, 
217497L, 219141L, 219235L, 219611L, 220974L, 221249L, 221704L, 
222197L, 226097L, 226987L, 228977L), organizations.api_path = c("organizations/tricked-dk", 
"organizations/xdirect", "organizations/lincoln-dental-supply", 
"organizations/scil-animal-care", "organizations/sportymob", 
"organizations/fanflipped", "organizations/afribaba-holdings", 
"organizations/rentokil", "organizations/counter-logic-gaming", 
"organizations/predictive-analytics", "organizations/curatern", 
"organizations/gotv-entertaining-africa", "organizations/gotv-entertaining-africa", 
"organizations/fst-biometrics", "organizations/picons", "organizations/eye", 
"organizations/inspiring-fifty", "organizations/fraudcracker", 
"organizations/saev", "organizations/take-eat-easy", "organizations/cgiar-consortium", 
"organizations/live-tile", "organizations/soko-insight", "organizations/leeds-beckett-university", 
"organizations/guialocal", "organizations/wisboo", "organizations/edukwest-europe", 
"organizations/demo-africa", "organizations/allafrica-global-media", 
"organizations/code-week", "organizations/spotcast-inc", "organizations/synergy-social-ventures", 
"organizations/lenoir-rhyne-college", "organizations/ceed-tech", 
"organizations/netocratic", "organizations/balkan-venture-forum", 
"organizations/adn-contents", "organizations/sarv-crm", "organizations/gooutmap", 
"organizations/fi-ware", "organizations/dla-venture-pipeline", 
"organizations/angels-on-time", "organizations/tangram-solutions", 
"organizations/start-with-seven", "organizations/games-in-asia", 
"organizations/openaxel", "organizations/z-safety-systems", "organizations/telkom-sa", 
"organizations/cadigo", "organizations/filepreviews"), type = c("Address", 
"Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", 
"Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", 
"Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", 
"Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", 
"Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", 
"Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", 
"Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", 
"Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", "Address", 
"Address"), uuid = c("f5d931f41c976de95e8e19d98c9d1e71", "e4cdc0eab5370addf2cfcc2968b352ed", 
"84bd97b962366ba892e9c9e21134c636", "f03a05df323aa842406e8a4652951876", 
"52bb2fcc51b56d2a6f124d1084b46c31", "fb3e017f18fdd8e25d350c0acb787d7a", 
"775a805b428c129b7e4a4cd724461868", "bee1141933033ac79da8eace50acafdc", 
"44e55ce5044b6c1c8bc3d3aef7df87bf", "00e163d78e1809063778e4766a18bdfb", 
"2a65aca53c8e39792b113464c681ea52", "41b8b2fd215158d9dcb49ba366b7a036", 
"923e0fbdea2e3c1da9f67b721b65d8e4", "d999ff11eae271f9876ec4e3075e4125", 
"e51603d3020a327edbfeec14f21cccc3", "9b9e58951d59ed2aec3ca0ab766116ed", 
"15e5998b1e8c3d4345c85e76f3dac240", "a22b40a3305de557315758a94080aa76", 
"b6332226dec612644868f7491a901f4a", "4a3f4401cc908be0a77185e7d3c9a206", 
"73dbe3fda355a357dee29caf5aa4dc99", "e85678b7bf1085432c63600319012a10", 
"7f5e79d588492491c012fbdb90122073", "f4e47d7927be2eacddfb960cee55dc6b", 
"5c59be51096e8c0a94f87b1de3689d42", "38548540aa739607dec960129cf12ba9", 
"952ab75de5ea8d85a44a8dcd432607bd", "e68ee31280619ce2f77b932f8daec571", 
"4bb54989ab4497e319d036c89427d8cf", "ae09b50b190db4a183bda9eccbe4cfce", 
"862eec31ebb44e73d0ece854ab314ce5", "6380fdab108b1fee616d847d7f392f6a", 
"85d6bd776b725d934d0bff98b2c83cad", "f7e3911becbbeb4dfec0418ed5f2b39a", 
"b5ef4f3d9660e23808ca0a0ed0e338bb", "da9861eded1a9a0e9bf6ba6a48aedf1e", 
"76e1d4c1a1c56c5fe2b1c21c656a3a69", "f3f5becd3a1693efca41bcc1af1703f6", 
"18ac74abae87d07ce3b11eb0dbd820a9", "e428d523943b2cc3aec47b72129b5fe6", 
"36e696fed157afe1602ca8fda46fa8cc", "329fb82b86a66a9e656f3c552430ceca", 
"b7d59665f2a8154e7359b9e290112460", "aa4ef592efedfd60816af1b8f46705dc", 
"56cc4caadab46e6badfc8d6dee7d42e1", "17c659034260a6b393f566f0499f4178", 
"e05c45df62761524de921aca8c489b44", "26e0ec01fc14f58419a5553bc2e0503a", 
"3d3b5834d32f858b65ee07fae02252cf", "49e224e43d352755a51e543c9d036a96"
), name = c("Headquarter", "xDirect", "Headquarters", "Headquarters", 
"Headquarters", "Main office", "Headquarters", "Headquarter", 
"Main office", "Main office", "Headquaters", "Headquarters", 
"Headquarters", "Headquarters", "HQ", "Headquarters", "HQ", "Headquarters", 
"Aberdeen (UK)", "Branch Office", "Headquarters", "HQ", "Africa", 
"Main Campus", "", "HQ", "HQ", "HQ", "Main office", "HQ", "Headquarters", 
"HQ", "Main Campus", "Headquarters", "HQ", "Main office", "Headquarters", 
"Headquarters", "Headquarters", "HQ", "", "HQ", "Main office", 
"HQ", "HQ", "HQ", "HQ", "Headquarters", "", "HQ"), street_1 = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "33 Lazarov St.", 
"", "", "", "Building 3, Sandgate Office Park", "Abercrombie Court", 
"", "1000, Avenue Agropolis Montpellier,", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "2 passage of Mulhouse City Hall", 
"GOLGASHT STREET, NO. 8", "", "", "", "Russia, Europe", "", "Three Seasons Office Park, Block A, 7 Spring Street", 
"", "", "Industrial Area Rotem Heulentakstraat 8", "178 Madiba Street Pretoria", 
"", ""), street_2 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "16 Desmond Street, Kramerville Sandton", 
"Arnhall Business Park", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "KDPSTY17489", "", "", "", 
"", "", "Rivonia, Sandton, South Africa", "", "", "Dilsen-Stokkem", 
"", "", ""), postal_code = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "AB32 6FE", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "68100", 
"19157", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "", ""), city = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Rishon Lezion", 
"", "", "", "", "Aberdeen, UK and Oslo, Norway", "", "France", 
"France", "", "", "Mex", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "France", "", "", "", "Usa", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "Usa", ""), city_web_path = c("location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"location/asia/b41404d28ecccaf512688fdd3afe73ee", "location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1", 
"location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1", "location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", 
"location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1", "location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1", 
"location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", "location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", 
"", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", 
"", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "", "", 
"location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", "", "", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", 
"location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1", "location/asia/b41404d28ecccaf512688fdd3afe73ee", 
"", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "", "location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", 
"location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1", 
"location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", "location/asia/b41404d28ecccaf512688fdd3afe73ee", 
"location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", "location/europe/6106f5dc823e5da840d751612c0b2c4e", 
"location/africa/5b194c3b3018b47df611ab142cdfd74c", "", "location/north-america/b25caef9a1b83a5d623293b2dfb6a1d1"
), region = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", ""), region_code2 = c("", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), region_web_path = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
""), country = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", ""), country_code2 = c("", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), country_code3 = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
""), country_web_path = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latitude = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    longitude = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), created_at = c(1472017733L, 
    1465290491L, 1462452917L, 1462449522L, 1453173099L, 1442981619L, 
    1441282477L, 1441188785L, 1440063839L, 1436866575L, 1449038192L, 
    1431511632L, 1431511671L, 1385115787L, 1426216594L, 1451463126L, 
    1425892972L, 1425395355L, 1366007686L, 1429092875L, 1422609471L, 
    1419929819L, 1425486709L, 1397988672L, 1397646249L, 1412939086L, 
    1412685691L, 1412669552L, 1412165155L, 1412059260L, 1427182640L, 
    1411738828L, 1397988677L, 1426923750L, 1410082123L, 1412660190L, 
    1422885253L, 1409737973L, 1453226669L, 1408033946L, 1390890580L, 
    1407478355L, 1407390601L, 1407497667L, 1406899810L, 1408455996L, 
    1406606186L, 1405405821L, 1396892107L, 1406895938L), updated_at = c(1472017733L, 
    1465290491L, 1462452917L, 1462449523L, 1453173099L, 1442981619L, 
    1441282599L, 1441188785L, 1440063840L, 1436866576L, 1449038328L, 
    1431511633L, 1431511671L, 1431452774L, 1426216595L, 1451463126L, 
    1425892973L, 1425395356L, 1424818704L, 1429092914L, 1422646398L, 
    1419967132L, 1425486709L, 1423708863L, 1423516571L, 1412939087L, 
    1412685692L, 1412669553L, 1412165258L, 1412059261L, 1427182641L, 
    1411738828L, 1415300534L, 1426923751L, 1410082123L, 1412660191L, 
    1422902286L, 1409737975L, 1453226669L, 1408033946L, 1416861739L, 
    1407478355L, 1407390602L, 1407497668L, 1406899810L, 1408455996L, 
    1406606187L, 1409264446L, 1416858194L, 1406895938L)), .Names = c("org_order", 
"organizations.api_path", "type", "uuid", "name", "street_1", 
"street_2", "postal_code", "city", "city_web_path", "region", 
"region_code2", "region_web_path", "country", "country_code2", 
"country_code3", "country_web_path", "latitude", "longitude", 
"created_at", "updated_at"), row.names = c(6712L, 23888L, 30537L, 
30568L, 66291L, 70998L, 74766L, 74967L, 77009L, 83681L, 89607L, 
93685L, 93686L, 94208L, 106079L, 107094L, 107242L, 108555L, 110439L, 
110980L, 114553L, 120627L, 123869L, 124297L, 133799L, 135863L, 
136578L, 136699L, 137802L, 138269L, 138377L, 138976L, 139449L, 
141300L, 143473L, 145303L, 145391L, 145574L, 146477L, 147807L, 
149247L, 149327L, 149650L, 150870L, 151106L, 151466L, 151892L, 
155304L, 156151L, 157890L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Consider sourcing a [list of countries](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries) and then matching words from your table against the available list, that would give a list of *clear hits* for country names that are mention in your table. Consider adding output `dput(yourData)` as the provided data is tedious to source in R. `read.delim(pipe("pbpaste"), sep = "")` fails due to the column structure.

Comment: You may consider to reshape your dataframe from wide to long form (e.g, using `melt`). So you will only have to search one column of data to find country names in. Later, you can reshape from long to wide again (e.g., `dcast`) thereby combining results as desired.

Comment: BTW: In the 2nd row of your sample data `C/Guatemala` is a Spanish street name. How do you want to handle this? Will this still be a country match?

Comment: @Uwe_Block At this stage I need to comb through all the geo data for possible misplaced country data (the country data is missing in these records). This is a first pass and I will probably have to manually sort out false positives.

Comment: @Uwe_Block Thanks for your your suggestion to melt, but I still need some kind of code to update the country column with the found patterns

Comment: @Konrad Sorry, I'm new to this. How do I attach data to my question? Just copy-paste at the bottom?

Comment: @syre paste output from `dput(yourData)`.

Comment: @Konrad just did that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm suggesting an approach which is based on two observations:

1. The country names do include entries such as  `"Hong Kong, Special Administrative Region of China"`, `"Korea, Republic of"`, `"Venezuela?(Bolivarian Republic of)"` which rarely will yield matches when used as pattern for `grep`. Either the list needs to be cleaned up beforehand or partial matching is required.
2. The OP commented: "*At this stage I need to comb through all the geo data for possible misplaced country data (the country data is missing in these records). This is a first pass and I will probably have to manually sort out false positives.*"

The basic idea is to split both the country names as well as the target text into words, find matching words (i.e., partial matches of country names with target text), and finally append *all* country names which do partially match to the appropriate rows of the target text.

### Prepare country names

`data.table` version 1.9.8 is used for performance reasons (please, run `packageVersion("data.table")` to verify that you have installed the most recent version from CRAN).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(countries)

# split country names into words
countries <- countries[, stringr::str_split(name, boundary("word")), by = name]

print(countries)
#               name          V1
#  1:    Afghanistan Afghanistan
#  2:  Aland Islands       Aland
#  3:  Aland Islands     Islands
#  4:        Albania     Albania
#  5:        Algeria     Algeria
# ---                           
#406: Western Sahara     Western
#407: Western Sahara      Sahara
#408:          Yemen       Yemen
#409:         Zambia      Zambia
#410:       Zimbabwe    Zimbabwe

# show top ten entries after split 
countries[, .N, by = V1][order(-N)][1:10]
#          V1  N
# 1:  Islands 17
# 2:       of 13
# 3:      and 12
# 4: Republic 12
# 5:    Saint  7
# 6:   United  5
# 7:   Island  4
# 8:    China  4
# 9:   Guinea  4
#10:   French  4

# remove some unspecific entries
countries <- countries[!V1 %chin% c("and", "of")]
```

### Prepare target text

```
# keep original row names as unique identifier for each record, verify uniqueness
setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)
stopifnot(!df[, anyDuplicated(rn)])

# reshape from wide to long form to have all target text in one column
mdf <- melt(df, id.vars = "rn")

# split target text into words
mdf <- mdf[, stringr::str_split(value, boundary("word")), 
           by = .(rn, variable, value)]
```

### Find matching words = partial match of country names with target text

```
# right join of mdf with countries on words, all rows of mdf are kept 
mw <- countries[mdf, on = .(V1)]
```

### Prepare result

For each unique row id, the country names which do have a partial match are collapsed in a character string which can be appended to the respective rows of the original `df`. `unique()` ensures that country names only appear once even in case of multiple partial matches (e.g., `"South Africa"` will have multiple matches on the words `"South"` and `"Africa"`).

I've decided to use slash `"/"` as character to separate the collapsed entries because slash seems not be used in country names while comma `","` already is.

```
# collapse country names which have a partial match
ccn <- mw[, .(pmcn = paste(sort(unique(name)), collapse = "/")), by = rn]

# append collapsed list of partially matching country names to original df by join on row id
result <- ccn[df, on = "rn"]
# re-order columns to have new column as last column
setcolorder(result, c(names(df), "pmcn"))

# show statistics on matches
result[, .N, by = pmcn]
#                                                                    pmcn  N
#1:                                                                       44
#2:                                                                Norway  1
#3:                                                                France  2
#4:                                                          South Africa  1
#5:                                  France/Holy See?(Vatican City State)  1
#6: South Africa/South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands/South Sudan  1
```

### Discussion of sample results

```
# show one row where partially matching country names where found
result[pmcn != ""][1]
#       rn org_order organizations.api_path    type                             uuid
#1: 110439    168297     organizations/saev Address b6332226dec612644868f7491a901f4a
#            name          street_1              street_2 postal_code
#1: Aberdeen (UK) Abercrombie Court Arnhall Business Park    AB32 6FE
#                            city city_web_path region region_code2 region_web_path
#1: Aberdeen, UK and Oslo, Norway                                                  
#   country country_code2 country_code3 country_web_path latitude longitude created_at
#1:                                                                         1366007686
#   updated_at   pmcn
#1: 1424818704 Norway
```

For this row a match was found on `Norway` from the `city` column but not on `UK` because the list of country names included `United Kingdom`.

```
result[pmcn != ""][5]
#       rn org_order     organizations.api_path    type
#1: 145391    214549 organizations/adn-contents Address
#                               uuid         name                        street_1
#1: 76e1d4c1a1c56c5fe2b1c21c656a3a69 Headquarters 2 passage of Mulhouse City Hall
#   street_2 postal_code   city city_web_path region region_code2 region_web_path
#1:                68100 France                                                  
#   country country_code2 country_code3 country_web_path latitude longitude created_at
#1:                                                                         1422885253
#   updated_at                                 pmcn
#1: 1422902286 France/Holy See?(Vatican City State)
```

For this row a match was found on `France` from the `city` column and a false positive for `Vatican City State` due to the word `City` in column `street_1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is more than I could hope for! A very minor comment: `mw <- countries[mdf, on = .(V1)]` didn't work for me but `mw <- countries[mdf, on = "V1"]` did.

Comment: Thank you. My bad, I probably forgot to mention that I'm using the latest  `data.table` version 1.9.8 which has been released to CRAN on 25NOV. Need to update my answer. Just to verify: which version are you using? Please run `packageVersion("data.table")` - Thank you.

Comment: I'm running 1.96, so I'm not up to date apparently :)

Comment: Another issue I've just noticed is that str_split by word boundary splits UTF-8 words like "Côte" (in "Côte d'Ivoire").

Comment: On Linux, `unlist(str_split("Côte d'Ivoire", boundary("word")))` returns `[1] "Côte"     "d'Ivoire"` as expected while `unlist(str_split("C?te d'Ivoire", boundary("word")))` returns [1] "C"        "te"       "d'Ivoire". The latter was split at the `?` which apparently has replaced the `ô` in the `dput` of the country names. Please, can you verify that there are no encoding issues in your data? BTW, I've seen a number of questions concerning encoding issues on SO recently.

Comment: I'm on Windows. "Côte d'Ivoire" was encoded in UTF-8 in OpenOffice, then loaded with read.csv and the UTF-8 argument and reads correctly in the data view (but not in the console, which I think is expected). Encoding(value) returns "unknown". Do I need to set encoding to "UTF-8" even though the data was explicitly loaded as UTF-8?

Comment: That is starting to evolve into another question, now. There are already questions & answers on SO, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129502/discussion-between-uwe-block-and-syre).