# Convert unicode to readable characters in R

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I have a .csv where the encoding returns "unknown" and "UTF-8" when using `Encoding(data)`. The text looks like this:

`<U+1042><U+1040><U+1042><U+1040> <U+1019><U+103D><U+102C>\n\n<U+1010><U+102D><U+102F><U+1004><U+1039><U+1038><U+103B><U+1015><U+100A><U+1039><U+1000><U+102D><U+102F><U+101C><U+1032> <U+1000><U+102C><U+1000><U+103C>`

I would like to turn it into a readable format, which in this case is Myanmar language, so something that looks a little like this:

`၂၀၂၀မွာတိုင္းျ`

Strangely, the text in this data used to be readable in RStudio, but at some point -- I don't know when -- this changed and I can only see the Unicode characters now. I have tried these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r) with no success.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
library(stringi)

string <- "<U+1042><U+1040><U+1042><U+1040> <U+1019><U+103D><U+102C>\n\n<U+1010><U+102D><U+102F><U+1004><U+1039><U+1038><U+103B><U+1015><U+100A><U+1039><U+1000><U+102D><U+102F><U+101C><U+1032> <U+1000><U+102C><U+1000><U+103C>" 

cat(stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(....)>", "\\\\u\\1", string)))
```

Which results in:

၂၀၂၀ မွာ

တိုင္းျပည္ကိုလဲ ကာကြ