# Unicode characters in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub, data-manipulation, diacritics

I have a data frame that containts polish diacritic signs however in my data frame they are presented as e.g. `ZESP\xc3\x93\xc5\x81 SZK\xc3\x93\xc5\x81` which should be `ZESPÓŁ SZKÓŁ`. I was trying to make a replace for all of those characeters: 
e.g.

```
x <- "SP\\xc3\\x93\\xc5\\x81KA"
x1 <- data.frame(x)

data <- data.frame(lapply(x1, function(df3) {
                    gsub("SP\\xc3\\x93\\xc5\\x81KA", "SPÓŁKA", df3)
              }))
```

However such a replace does not work. How to deal with those type of data frames? How to force it to display correct diacritic signs?

**I have added a fully reproducible example. Any ideas? Some solutions?**

Comment: Try `utf8::utf8_encode(x)` Where `x <- "SP\\xc3\\x93\\xc5\\x81KA"`

Comment: On the entire data frame?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739800/convert-unicode-to-readable-characters-in-r)?

Comment: @markus does not work

Comment: @Sotos good idea it somehow works but I have no idea as of now how to force it to work with Polish language and all characters at once

Comment: @mmkaczmarek123 Can create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @markus will do my best to try to create it

Comment: @markus reproducible example was added

Comment: You have any ideas? Any solutions?